# xelatex rotates pdf image

Tags: xetex, includegraphics

Consider this example

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                                                                             
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{CMS-MUO-16-001_Figure_008-a.pdf}                                                                                                                                   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The pdf image can be downloaded from https://cms-results.web.cern.ch/cms-results/public-results/publications/MUO-16-001/CMS-MUO-16-001_Figure_008-a.pdf

When compiled with `xelatex` of TexLive 2017 the image is rotated to -90 degrees.

What is the cause and the solution? Upgrading to a new TexLive version is also an acceptable solution.

Comment: For me it's the same for `xelatex` as for `pdflatex` or `lualatex`... What version do you have?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik TexLive 2017

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, I managed to solve the problem by uninstalling TexLive 2017 and installing TexLive 2018

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to answer you. Yes. I too have TeXLive 2018. Quite strange, though, XeTeX rotating the picture. Very odd... Perhaps you should post an answer in case someone else experiences the same issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by uninstalling TexLive 2017 and installing TexLive 2018.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly (note that it works in TL2018). As you are asking for a solution for TL2017 this does not answer your own question…